# Ubuntu subdomain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a subdomain with Apache2 on my Ubuntu droplet, I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) to the T but every time I navigate to my subdomain, I get the default apache landing page.

So I've set up separate conf files for both my main and sub domains,

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mainsite.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mainsite/public_html
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/submainsite/public_html
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't have much server side experience, so please pardon my ignorance on the matter.

**EDIT:**

Both sites are linked, I did run `a2ensite`.

When running `apachectl -S` I get:

```
 default server sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mainsite.conf:1)
         alias example.com
```

Comment: The obvious questions are: did you restart apache after checking the configuration with `apachectl configtest` ; did you place an IndexDocument in the DocumentRoot of the subdomain; which virtual hosts are shown by `apachectl -S` ? And IIRC writing to the same log files from within two different VirtualHost entries is a no no.

Comment: are both sites linked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` i.e. did you run `a2ensite sub`?

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I have edited my question, and have added the info you've enquired about. I have added both sites, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the default server in `000-default.conf` as `sub.example.com` and it is pointed to the Apache test page. Because it comes first, it overrides the *second* `sub.example.com` virtual host you had defined in `sub.conf`.

To fix the problem, edit `000-default.conf` and remove `ServerName sub.example.com` from it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I had a look at `000-default.conf`, all that was defined was ServerAdmin, DocumentRoot, ErrorLog and CustomLog. It was pointing to the apache test page though, and after commenting everything out, disabling 000-default with `a2dissite 000-default` and restarting apache, it seems to be working, thanks for the assist! :)